# How to import a file named with a variable

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-import, importerror

Im trying to do the following:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
yestarday_file = datetime.strftime(datetime.now() - timedelta(1), '%m-%d-%Y' + ".xlsx")
```

Then, once I have that (which is going to iterate every day), I will run these :

```
path = "/Users/u6075486/Desktop/Davenport/QA/"
df = pd.read_csv(f'{path}{yestarday_file}/')
```

I also try these

```
df = pd.read_csv(f'{path}{yestarday_file}')
```

Without the last backslash

But none of them worked and I got these error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xdb in position 1: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: Ok, so its possibly an encoding issue

Comment: can you try to print(f'{path}{yestarday_file}')

This would make it more clear as to what file you're trying to access.

Comment: [`xlsx` files are **not** `csv` files!](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

Comment: Note that an `xlsx` is a bunch of zipped xml, a csv is a delimited text file. These are vastly different formats. Use `pd.read_excel` instead

Comment: Thank you to everyone, it was a very silly mistake.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to `read_csv` an Excel file. Use [`read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) instead!